# Suppress specific holes in a pattern using Solidworks API

Tags: vba, api, solidworks

I'm working on a project, where I need to suppress only specific holes in a linear pattern. For example, I have 20 holes in a row, and I need to suppress holes 12, 13, and 14. There is a feature in Solidworks, where you can suppress referenced copies in a linear pattern, but I haven't found out yet how to select it using API. Maybe you can help me.

Here is the code I have so far for suppressing the whole feature, it might help:

```
Dim swApp As Object
Dim Part As Object
Dim Feature As SldWorks.Feature
Dim featureName As String
Dim action As String
Dim searchStr As String

Sub main()
 
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    
    searchStr = "Lineares Muster1"
    action = "Unsuppress"
    
    swApp.ActivateDoc "LProfilL"
    
        Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
        Set PartDocExt = Part.Extension
        Set Feature = Part.FirstFeature

        Do While Not Feature Is Nothing

            Let featureName = Feature.Name
            
            If InStr(1, featureName, searchStr, 1) Then
                status = PartDocExt.SelectByID2(featureName, "BODYFEATURE", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
                
                If (action = "Suppress") Then
                        status = Part.EditSuppress2()
                        
                    ElseIf (action = "Unsuppress") Then
                        status = Part.EditUnsuppress2()
                        
                End If
                
            End If
            Set Feature = Feature.GetNextFeature()
            
        Loop
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some more research i found out about "SkippedItemArray":

```
Dim swApp As Object
Dim Part As Object
Dim skip As Variant
Dim skip2(0 To 3) As Long

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc

    Part.SelectByID "Lineares Muster1", "BODYFEATURE", 0, 0, 0

    Set SelMan = Part.SelectionManager

    Set Feature = SelMan.GetSelectedObject5(1)

    Set FeatureData = Feature.GetDefinition

    skip = FeatureData.SkippedItemArray

    skip2(0) = 4

    skip2(1) = 5

    skip2(2) = 6

    skip2(3) = 7

    skip = skip2

    FeatureData.SkippedItemArray = (skip)

    Feature.ModifyDefinition FeatureData, Part, Nothing

    FeatureData.ReleaseSelectionAccess

End Sub
```